# SPFx 'Field Customizer' puts restrictions on CSS ??

Tags: css, spfx, client-side-rendering, spfx-webparts

In the [SPFx video at Buid17](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8032)

there is an example for the new (JSLink/CSR replacement) "Field Customizer" blurring sensitive information

[image]

They use MouseEvents (and more code) to swap a whole DIV

[image]

[image]

**Question:** Is this a case of a "developer" not knowing anything about Front-End development?

Or is there a restriction on CSS and do we now need 30+ lines of code for what can be done with one CSS selector?

```
.blurredCell:hover{
   filter:none;
}
```

**Does this mean CSS is scoped to one Field?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case using the `:hover` selector would be enough theoretically. The sample however, also illustrates the capability that should it be necessary, you could change not only the styling but the actual contents of what's being rendered.

Comment: So a CSS selector is applied to the whole page?

Comment: Assuming extensions work the same way as web parts (this is yet to be verified once extensions are publicly released), it depends how you define CSS: if you define your selector as global, it will apply to all matching elements on the page. If you follow Microsoft's suggestions to scope your selectors to avoid conflicts then it would apply to your particular customizer applied to the particular field.

Comment: "Assuming" .. so there is no definite answer yet...  Ah well.. I am already moving one application from O365 to AWS